# Winforms stop user from entering other language character than english in textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, localization, .net-2.0

I have some textboxes which are mapped to primary key fields in the database and I don't want the users to write in any language other than english or numbers or undersore even if the use manually switches the input language to anything else. How can I achieve the same. I'm on .net 2.0 so no fancy stuff. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your input using `Regex`. 
This pattern will match any English letter `[a-zA-Z]`

For example Russian ю will not match

```
Match m = Regex.Match("ю", "[a-zA-Z]");
```

Handle the KeyPress event to achieve needed functionality

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !Regex.Match(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "[a-zA-Z]").Success;
    }
```

Comment: I was hoping that we could entirely eliminate the other language typing instead of validating the input.

Comment: I've edited my anwser, you will not see any input other than you wish. Or would do you mean saying eliminating? :)

Comment: Arabic charaters are still showing success. I wrote `e.Handled = Regex.Match(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "[a-zA-Z]*?").Success`

Comment: @SohamDasgupta I've edited my answer and tested it with Arabic and Russian symbols, should work now ;)